# Mariadb cluster doesn't start on reboot

Tags: centos, cluster, mariadb

I make cluster for mariadb on 3 VMs(called controller1, controller2, controller3), them works fine.

But however, after I reboot the VMs, the mariadb is not start:

```
[root@controller1 ~]# rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@controller1 ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@controller1: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@controller1]

rabbit@controller1:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on controller1
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on controller1
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-24@controller1'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: MpCdZgRS3T3SYr+AfOYx+A==
```

In normal we know if we restart the cluster nodes the mariadb cluster will restart too.

My VMs system is CentOS 7.2, and I am sure the ntp date is the same.